# Express/React app refresh issue on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, react-router

My React app with Express backend is hosted on Heroku, and all of the routing works as expected until the page refreshes.  Refreshing the page either programmatically, or with the refresh button the page returns:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

The back and forward buttons (which work before refreshing) cease to work and the only way to get the app back is to navigate to the "/".  Everything works correctly then until the next refresh.

My server routes :

```
router.use("/api/skus", skuRoutes);
router.use("/api/categories", categoryRoutes);

// serve static files if in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  router.use(express.static("client/build"));

  router.get("*", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "client", "build", "index.html")
    );
  });
}
```

I have read many, many other similar questions on here and many tutorials on using react router on Heroku, but I haven't found a solution that works for me.

I have already tried the solutions that use a static.json file:

```
{
    "root": "build/",
    "clean_urls": false,
    "routes": {
      "/**": "index.html"
    }
  }
```

, and adding the create-react-app buildpack to Heroku, but these do not work for me.

GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/JonathanDPotter/inventory).

Current deployment [here](https://whispering-oasis-61591.herokuapp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed by changing my BrowserRouter to a HashRouter.  Now refreshes work perfectly.